# php echo file name from image file

Tags: php

Hello everyone i need some help in this file can i do this
i work in new script that has this PHP configuration

```
<?php
function random_pic($dir, $nf=3)
{
$files = glob($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.jpg');
shuffle($files);
return array_pop($files);
}
//$number = rand(); ?v=$number
$path = 'images';
$file_1 = random_pic($path, 1);
$image  = file_get_contents($file_1);
$og_img = base64_encode($image); 
?>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta property="og:title" content="This is your Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://YourDomain.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://YourDomain.com/<?php echo $file_1 ?>" />
```

the echo configuration change the image file in every reload on the og:image what i want is how can do the same thing on og:title change the title automatically withe the name of the image that will show on og:image how to do that

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

check [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php), it should take your $file_1 path and return it's name with (including extension).

`basename($file_1)`

so you will change this line:

`<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo basename($file_1)?>" />`